# ionic 3 woocommerce registeration login api working checkout only showing error any one guide me

Tags: ionic3

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of

```
401 (Unauthorized)
:8100/#/menu/home:1 Failed to load

http://website.in/wc-api/v3/orders?oauth_consumer_key=ck_b68cd0e26459a0f567a179db1eeaf35bec7caf8c2d&oauth_nonce=fTUiFkOHVfOnxzMv7Nv51RqWUSibewXm&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1514263587&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=Kf0%2Bba%2BefZtRA6sZOcDopeyuCBqxZ4cN1oRgRW6zmYc%3D`


: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
bluebird.js:1545 Unhandled rejection TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following code in your .htaccess file on the top. You can find this file in the root of your WordPress.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $l [R=200,L]
```

Also enable CORS on your browser.